# unable purchase packaged app with google wallet

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app, android-pay

I've created a packaged app for chrome web store. For test reasons I've tried to buy my own app using another google account with another credit card and recieved an error:

> Uh oh. There was a problem.
>
> We couldn't start your purchase because of a technical issue. Details
>   of the problem below: There is an error in the setup for your
>   purchase. Please contact the merchant about this issue.

What might be a reason of this error?

Thanks!

Comment: `For test reasons I've tried to buy my own app` - you can't buy from yourself...

Comment: And why not exactly? I've made another account with another credit card. My friend can not buy it as well.

Comment: Am not a Googler, just know that you [can't buy from yourself](https://support.google.com/payments/answer/1387970?hl=en). What are the details of the error (any other detail)?

Comment: Maybe your server timed out for the callback?  What's in the returned error param?

Comment: Thanks all for helping. Problem dissapeared some how... didn't do anything to fix it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks all for helping. Problem dissapeared some how... didn't do anything to fix it...